# How to do dir specific merges in a git repo

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I've two branches rel/1.0 and rel/2.0 with a dir structure of src, testcases in both branches. QA developers supposed to touch only files under testcases dir in both branches. Now I wanted to merge only testcases dir from rel/1.0 to rel/2.0 and exclude all changes (during merge) under src dir which the core developers will merge those changes later.

How to achieve this?

When I do reset and revert during merge for all files under src, it's not allowing developers to merge src changes from 1.0 to 2.0 later, since it's saying 'everything up-to date'. I believe the git merge history is marked as merged for all files.

Comment: not looking for cherry-pick option/answer, since the changes in branches huge in count

Comment: You will have to merge in the changes, without recording it as a merge commit. If you end up with a merge commit you will have problems merging in the other changes later.

Comment: How to merge without recording it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use `subtree` merge here

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

This is to merge test directory from `rel/1.0` into `rel/2.0`

```
 git checkout rel/2.0
 git merge --no-ff -s recursive -X subtree=test rel/1.0 (resolve conflicts if any)
 git push origin rel/2.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me and I'm able to see the whole rel/1.0 changes including src dir changes in the merge workspace. I'm using git ver 2.10.x on linux host